# Conversion of matrix numbers to matrix ASCII?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I program a basic script to generate in python3 by numpy a square matrix of integers between 33 and 255. I can reach this point very easy, but the problem is next:
I try to convert this numbers in ASCII symbols in a square matrix. But I'm not found a solution after a search in Internet or StackOver Flow. This is my code:

```
#!usr/bin/env/python3.6
# imports
import numpy as np
import random
# Generated random matrix of 25 spaces, 
# where placed ramdom number between 0 to 255,
# and store in a variable.
matrix = np.random.randint(33,255, size=(5, 5))

# This shows the matrix of integer numbers.
print(matrix) # Good!!!
# This translate  matrix of number to ASCII table symbols:
for matrix in store:
    print(chr(matrix)) # BANG! Error, my honey.
```

Comment: What is `store`?  `matrix` in the loop is not the global `matrix`.  `chr` is a Python function that takes ONE number and returns ONE character.

Comment: Hello, finally I do a little improve the code included in a function, which will be used in a major program:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is `store` in your code. After fixing this bug, it works

```
#!usr/bin/env/python3.6
# imports
import numpy as np
import random
# Generated random matrix of 25 spaces, 
# where placed ramdom number between 0 to 255,
# and store in a variable.
matrix = np.random.randint(33,255, size=(5, 5))

# This shows the matrix of integer numbers.
print(matrix) # Good!!!
# This translate  matrix of number to ASCII table symbols:
for col in range(5):
    for row in range(5):
        print(chr(matrix[row][col]), end=' ')
    print('\n') # Solved, my honey.
```

The output is-

```
[[ 86 159  40 221 211]
 [166 224 213 252 160]
 [155 160 111 109 164]
 [ 98 190  34 250  40]
 [115 228  59 139 221]]

V ¦  b s 
 à   ¾ ä 
( Õ o " ; 
Ý ü m ú  
Ó   ¤ ( Ý
```

Comment: OP doesn't ask how to print the characters, they are asking for a "matrix" containing them.

Comment: @PaulPanzer, the OP is doing a print within a loop.  That suggests he's more interested in the display, than with having a character matrix to use later.  I'd like this answer better if the characters lined up in columns.

Comment: @hpaulj. Maybe. Well, I'm sure they'll make themselves clear, unless they don't.

Comment: I'd iterate on `row` first.  and index with `matrix[row, col]`.

Comment: Hi, I've seen both solutions. The goal is to create a random ASCII symbol matrix. To then use it in a desktop application in PyQt. That is the final goal, although both are right. Thanks for your help. :-)

Answer (score 1):

This

```
dtype = np.uint16 if np.dtype('U1').itemsize==2 else np.uint32
matrix.astype(dtype).view('U1')
array([['Ö', '´', 'O', 'i', '\x98'],
       ['à', 'ü', 'S', 'm', 'æ'],
       ['ý', 'm', '#', 'ö', 'u'],
       ['±', 'l', '\x82', 'O', 'È'],
       ['h', '&', '\x82', 'ª', '\xad']],
      dtype='<U1')
```

kind of works. Not 100% sure it's ASCII, though. But it does the same as `chr`:

```
import pprint
>>> pprint.pprint([[chr(number) for number in row] for row in matrix])
[['Ö', '´', 'O', 'i', '\x98'],
 ['à', 'ü', 'S', 'm', 'æ'],
 ['ý', 'm', '#', 'ö', 'u'],
 ['±', 'l', '\x82', 'O', 'È'],
 ['h', '&', '\x82', 'ª', '\xad']]
```

What we are doing is to first cast to `uint16` or `uint32` because `U` dtype appears to have 2 or 4 bytes per character. We then viewcast to `U1` to reinterpret the numbers as characters and that's it.

Comment: Hi, I've seen both solutions. The goal is to create a random ASCII symbol matrix. To then use it in a desktop application in PyQt. That is the final goal, although both are right. Thanks for your help. :-)